# Eine Frage zu „genügend“: Ein Adjektiv oder Adverb? || A question on "genügend": an adjective or adverb?

Tags: adjective, standard-german, adverb, semantics

---Diese Frage ist auf zwei Sprachen geschrieben.---

Hallo Zusammen,

heute habe ich einen Satz in der [Zeit Wissen](https://www.zeit.de/zeit-wissen/2013/05/friedrich-von-borries-interview-nachhaltigkeit-verkehr/seite-2) gelesen, nämlich „Erreicht man mit solchen kulturellen Angeboten **genügend** Menschen, um etwas zu bewegen?“ Aber wie genügend ohne Flexionsendung steht, weiß ich nicht so genau. Habt Ihr eine Idee?

---

I recently came across a sentence in [Zeit Wissen](https://www.zeit.de/zeit-wissen/2013/05/friedrich-von-borries-interview-nachhaltigkeit-verkehr/seite-2):

Erreicht man mit solchen kulturellen Angeboten **genügend** Menschen, um etwas zu bewegen?

I am not sure if genügend here serves as an adjective modifying Menschen--in this case to my surprise it has no case ending agreeing with Menschen--or it simply functions as an adverb. But if genügend ***does*** agree with Menschen, is it inflectionless?

Thanks for clarifying.
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bei ["genügend"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/genuegend_Indefinitpronomen_ausreichend) handelt es sich hier nicht um ein Adjektiv sondern um ein Indefinitpronomen, vergleichbar zu Pluralpronomina wie "viele", "wenige" oder "einige". Genauso wie diese Zahlwörter wird "genügend" nicht flektiert. Es kann dafür aber natürlich nur vor Pluralen stehen.

In diesem Kontext wäre ein Synonym zu "genügend" auch "genug", das in die gleiche Kategorie fällt:

> Erreicht man mit solchen kulturellen Angeboten genug Menschen, um etwas zu bewegen?

Comment: Jetzt ist alles klar. Ich bedanke mich für deine schöne Erklärung.

Comment: @JoeHoffman Wenn du denkst, dass eine Antwort deine Frage ausreichend beantwortet, kannst Du sie mit dem Häkchen als "akzeptiert" markieren.